# scala : it is impossible to put a tuple as a function's argument

Tags: scala, tuples

I can't pass a tuple as a method parameter:

```
scala> val c:Stream[(Int,Int,Int)]= Stream.iterate((1, 0, 1))((a:Int,b:Int,c:Int) => (b,c,a+b))
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int, Int) => (Int, Int, Int)
 required: ((Int, Int, Int)) => (Int, Int, Int)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as the function literal:

```
(x:Int) => x + 1
```

is a function of one argument, the following

```
(x:Int, y: Int, z: Int) => x + y + z
```

is a function of three arguments, not one argument of a 3tuple

You can make this work neatly using a `case` statement:

```
scala> val c: Stream[(Int,Int,Int)] = 
       Stream.iterate((1, 0, 1)){ case (a, b, c) => (b, c, a+b) }

c: Stream[(Int, Int, Int)] = Stream((1,0,1), ?)
```

An alternative is to pass the tuple, but that's really ugly due to all the `_1` accessors:

```
scala> val c:Stream[(Int,Int,Int)] = 
         Stream.iterate((1, 0, 1))( t => (t._2, t._3, t._1 + t._2) )

c: Stream[(Int, Int, Int)] = Stream((1,0,1), ?)
```

Comment: it works, thank you. In fact I tried something like this (the use of case) but I did not put the case between curly brackets. Why simple brackets do not work?

Comment: @lolveley Because `case` is not a `simple expression`, which is all that is allowed inside `()` argument lists

Comment: Another issue with `case` is you could get runtime errors if your types or number of arguments get out of sync. :(

Comment: In some contexts, yes - but here the Stream is already constrained to `(Int,Int,Int)` so `case` will always succeed

Answer (score 4):

The lambda `(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int) => (b,c,a+b)` is a function taking three arguments. You want it to take one tuple, so you can write `((a:Int,b:Int,c:Int)) => (b,c,a+b)`. But this gives an error!

```
error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple3,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, ..., param3) => ... }
       (((a:Int,b:Int,c:Int)) => (b,c,a+b))
         ^
```

Luckily, the error suggests a solution: `{ case (a, b, c) => (b, c, a+b) }`

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use the `tupled` option:

```
def a = (x:Int, y: Int, z: Int) => x + y + z).tupled
val sum = a((1,2,3))
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the expression `(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int) => (b,c,a+b)` defines a lambda with three arguments, and you need one decomposed argument.